# Sending email in Xammp

Tags: php, email, xampp, gmail

I am trying to send email through a Gmail account using xammp (im using v3.2.2). I am also using windows 8 and ive read on some adjustments that need to be made like;

- Running Xammp as an administrator
- changing compatibility of sendmail.exe and also lettin it run as an administrator

i have implemented these changes but i think something is still missing coz the mail() still doesnt work here is what my file looks like

[PHP.ini]

```
    ; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
;SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port=587

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = ethicssystem@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail().
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header=off

; The path to a log file that will log all mail() calls. Log entries include
; the full path of the script, line number, To address and headers.
;mail.log =
; Log mail to syslog (Event Log on Windows).
;mail.log = syslog
```

[Sendmail Configurations]

```
; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

;smtp_server=mail.mydomain.com

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com


; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=587

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=something@gmail.com
auth_password=mypassword

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

;pop3_server=
;pop3_username=
;pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=something@gmail.com

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=
```

Comment: this line `sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"` looks wrong to me.. why so many quotes?

Comment: :D I tried doing the same thing with wamp. I searched everywhere, ended installing many email servers locally but then I got tired of that I just gave up :P I hope someone will post a working example too.

Comment: @DevDonkey those slashes are used to escape the quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating Sendmail Path to :

```
sendmail_path = "C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

also these following config : -

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

smtp_port=465

auth_username=USERNAME@gmail.com    
auth_password=PASSWORD

force_sender=USERNAME@gmail.com
```

obviously update the auth_username and force_sender with your email and auth_password with your password

Comment: it dosesnt work...i got this from the error log                                         [Fri Apr 08 10:14:33.250754 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3480:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Apr 08 10:14:33.849790 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 3480:tid 376] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: stop apache, mysql and Quit the xampp control panel. and re-run as administrator and try again ?